# List all indexes that not in use anymore in database, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I am trying to find, on a specific database, indexes which are not in use anymore using PostgreSQL on version 9.5.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will give you relatively unused indexes (idx_scan<50):

```
SELECT schemaname || '.' || relname AS table,
       indexrelname AS index,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(i.indexrelid)) AS index_size,
       idx_scan as index_scans
FROM pg_stat_user_indexes ui
  JOIN pg_index i ON ui.indexrelid = i.indexrelid
WHERE NOT indisunique 
  AND idx_scan < 50 
  AND pg_relation_size(relid) > 5 * 8192
ORDER BY pg_relation_size(i.indexrelid) / nullif(idx_scan, 0) DESC NULLS FIRST,
      pg_relation_size(i.indexrelid) DESC;
```